# Type Error: e is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular v1.3.0-beta.7. I keep getting;

```
Type Error: e is not a function
```

on line 10028. Full stack trace;

```
Type Error: e is not a fuction                                             angular.js:10028
    at angular.js:14321
    at e (angular.js:4426)
    at angular.js:4727
    (anonymous function)@angular.js:10028
    (anonymous function)@angular.js:7349
    (anonymous function)@angular.js:14324
    e                   @angular.js:4426
    (anonymous function)@angular.js:4727
```

I wish I can share my code but it is really very big. And it is happening, when an object updated from UI. When this object is updated, I do some ajax requests. This error occurs on sometimes before request result and sometimes after request result. I could not find when and why this is happening.

What can be the reason and how can I fix this problem.

Comment: give us the code, ty

Comment: If you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` it should give a clearer explanation, please update once you've done that

Comment: As I said, there are lots of code on different files. It will be really difficult to understand. It is approximately 5k.

Comment: It's look like a syntax error, I think you are calling non-function method or variable with a function syntax.

Comment: @MartijnWelker, yes I am using angular.min.js but I have aslo map file. So, this error coming according to angular.js

Comment: @oguzhan00, yeah probably but I only call $scope.$apply() of angular. Except this, for this process I don't call any angular function.

Comment: Thanks for commands, it was my mistake but I don't understand why angular gives such an error. Never mind, I solved the problem :)

Comment: how did you solve this ?

Comment: My mistake was, forgetting to define a function.

Answer (score 0):

if there is $window in your controller function please remove it.

before :

```
function ($scope, $window, $http, $timeout, $filter, $sce) {
}
```

after:

```
function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $filter, $sce) {
}
```